# Excel - How to HIGHLIGHT entire row with specific NUMBER value match, (this specific value is output result from another conditional formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

Excel - How to HIGHLIGHT entire row with specific NUMBER value match, 
(this specific value is output result from another conditional formula) 
With this attached excel screen shot "J" and "K" showing formula result, where J showing current sheet result, AND K showing result of another excel file. Now I want to HIGHTLIGHT entire ROW when number 3 appear in J or K or both column. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a new rule with a formula. Select the range, assuming it starts in row 1. Then the formula will be

```
=or($J1=3,$K1=3)
```

Note that there is a $ sign in front of the column letter to make the column fixed, but the row reference is relative. Apply that rule to cells A to K in rows 1 to all the rows you want below.

If your data does not start in row 1, adjust the formula accordingly.

Depending on your regional settings, you may need a semicolon instead of a comma in the formula.